# How to convert cropped file into file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to crop an image, I used `ImageCropper()`.

```
CroppedFile? croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(sourcePath: file.path);
```

How to convert this `croppedFile` into File?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the path property of the CroppedFile class to give you the file path as a string. Convert this path to a file type using File(), like so...

```
yourFile = File(croppedFile!.path);
```